# "Regrouping" data from nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, group-by, python-2.x, python-itertools

I have a JSON document like this:

```
{
'item1':{
   'value':[a,b],
   'number':1
  },
'item2':{
    'value':[a],
    'number':2
  },
 'item3':{
    'value':[b],
    'number':3
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get item names grouped by values?

Here's what I want:

```
a: item1, item2
b: item1, item3
```

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
l = sorted(l.iteritems())
for key, group in groupby(l,key=lambda x:x['value']):
   print key, group
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, that's not JSON.

Strings in JSON have double, not single quotes, and the unquoted tokens `a` and `b` are meaningless in JSON. Assuming that your actual document looks something like this:

```
{
  "item1": {
    "value": ["a", "b"],
    "number": 1
  },
  "item2": {
    "value": ["a"],
    "number": 2
  },
  "item3": {
    "value": ["b"],
    "number": 3
  }
}
```

… and you've loaded it into a Python dictionary `data`, you can get the output you want as follows:

```
grouped = {}
for key, subdict in data.items():
    for value in subdict['value']:
        grouped.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
```

Which will leave you with `grouped` looking like this:

```
{
    'a': ['item2', 'item1'],
    'b': ['item3', 'item1']
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Sorry for my wrong JSON formatting.